# adding an htmlwidget to a the popup of a leaflet object

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, dygraphs, htmlwidgets

I am using R to combine a leaflet object and an dygraph.

In particular I would like a dygraph (and ideally any htmlwidget) to appear as the popup to points on a map.

below is the code I am roughly trying to produce.

Ideally when the user clicks on the marker, the dygraph should appear in the popup.

```
  # example dygraph
  library(dygraphs)
  lungDeaths <- cbind(mdeaths, fdeaths)
  dygraph(lungDeaths)
  dd <- .Last.value

  # example leaflet map
  library(leaflet)
  leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>% 
    addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, 
               popup="The birthplace of R")
  ll <- .Last.value

  # I would like to be able to incorporate the dygraph as the popup,
  # however the below doesn't work.
  ll %>% addMarkers(lng=174.769, lat=-36.853,
                    popup=dd)


  # the end goal is to have this combined in a shiny output
  # below is a rough skeleton to add what I would expect to code
  # in order to be able to add the dygraph into the popup
  library(shiny)
  library(leaflet)
  library(dygraphs)

  ui <- fluidPage(
    leafletOutput("mymap")
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet() %>%
        addTiles() %>% 
        addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, 
                   popup=dygraph(lungDeaths))

    })
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using `mapview::popupGraph` which allows to include static as well as htmlwidgets based graphs in popups. The relevant line in your example to change is:

```
ll %>% addMarkers(lng=174.769, lat=-36.853,
                  popup=mapview::popupGraph(dd, type = "html"))
```

Note, theses html popups are embedded via an iframe, so there may be some unexpected behaviour especially when there is not enough space. With the github version of **leaflet** you can change the size of the popup to suit your needs. The CRAN version allows only 300px in width (if I am not mistaken).

Comment: Thank you! For a large set of points, do you have any suggestions on how to get different graphs for each point?

Comment: Try passing a list of graphs. See `### example: html -----` (last example) in `?popupGraph`. Though be aware that for a large set of points this can become very slow and unresponsive as you are cramming a lot of html code into one page.